# Ansible: Excessive duplication of text when merging multiple files into a single file

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible playbook that reaches out to several Cisco devices, collects the results of "show" commands from each one and subsequently creates individual files containing that output.  The playbook then merges all of those files into a single file.

However, the single, merged file has a lot of duplication in it and I'm not sure why. Can anyone help me figure out how to prevent this duplication? Thanks!

**Playbook**:

```
---
- 
  name: Lets Learn MORE YAML
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

    - name: Sending a simple Cisco IOS command
      cisco.ios.ios_command:
        commands: 
          - show ip interface brief
      register: Bob


    - debug: var=Bob.stdout_lines


    - name: Send output to file
      copy: content="{{Bob.stdout[0]}}" dest=/etc/ansible/YAML_Files/Config-Change-Logs/{{inventory_hostname}}.txt

    - name: Prepend line to file
      blockinfile:
          path: /etc/ansible/YAML_Files/Config-Change-Logs/{{inventory_hostname}}.txt
          block: |
            ""
            "{{inventory_hostname}}"
          insertbefore: BOF

    - name: Merge All Files Into One
      assemble:
        src: /etc/ansible/YAML_Files/Config-Change-Logs/
        dest: /etc/ansible/YAML_Files/Config-Change-Logs/MergedFile.txt
```

**Resulting (Merged) File**:

```
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
""
"CSR-1"
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
GigabitEthernet1       unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet2       10.21.21.11     YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet3       unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet4       unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet5       211.11.11.11    YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet6       unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet7       unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet8       unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet9       unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet10      unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
""
"CSR-1"
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
GigabitEthernet1       unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet2       10.21.21.11     YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet3       unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet4       unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet5       211.11.11.11    YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet6       unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet7       unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet8       unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet9       unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet10      unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
""
"CSR-1"
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
GigabitEthernet1       unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet2       10.21.21.11     YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet3       unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet4       unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet5       211.11.11.11    YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet6       unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet7       unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet8       unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet9       unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet10      unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
""
"CSR-1"
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
GigabitEthernet1       unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet2       10.21.21.11     YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet3       unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet4       unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet5       211.11.11.11    YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet6       unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet7       unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet8       unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet9       unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet10      unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
""
"SW-2"
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
GigabitEthernet0/0     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/1     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/2     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/3     unassigned      YES unset  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet1/0     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet1/1     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet1/2     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet1/3     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet2/0     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet2/1     unassigned      YES unset  up                    up      
Vlan123                123.123.123.2   YES manual up                    up
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
""
"r1"
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
GigabitEthernet0/0         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/1         123.123.123.1   YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/2         10.12.12.1      YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/3         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/4         unassigned      YES manual administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/5         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/6         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/7         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/8         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/9         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
Loopback0                  111.111.111.1   YES manual up                    up
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
""
"r2"
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
GigabitEthernet0/0         10.22.22.2      YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/1         10.21.21.2      YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/2         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/3         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/4         10.12.12.2      YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/5         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/6         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/7         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/8         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/9         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
Loopback0                  222.222.222.222 YES TFTP   up                    up
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
""
"r3"
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
GigabitEthernet0/0         123.123.123.3   YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/1         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/2         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/3         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/4         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/5         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/6         32.32.32.3      YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/7         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/8         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/9         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
""
"SW-2"
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
GigabitEthernet0/0     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/1     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/2     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/3     unassigned      YES unset  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet1/0     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet1/1     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet1/2     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet1/3     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet2/0     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet2/1     unassigned      YES unset  up                    up      
Vlan123                123.123.123.2   YES manual up                    up
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
""
"r1"
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
GigabitEthernet0/0         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/1         123.123.123.1   YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/2         10.12.12.1      YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/3         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/4         unassigned      YES manual administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/5         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/6         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/7         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/8         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/9         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
Loopback0                  111.111.111.1   YES manual up                    up
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
""
"r2"
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
GigabitEthernet0/0         10.22.22.2      YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/1         10.21.21.2      YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/2         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/3         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/4         10.12.12.2      YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/5         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/6         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/7         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/8         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/9         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
Loopback0                  222.222.222.222 YES TFTP   up                    up
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
""
"r3"
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
GigabitEthernet0/0         123.123.123.3   YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/1         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/2         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/3         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/4         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/5         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/6         32.32.32.3      YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/7         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/8         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/9         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
""
"SW-2"
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
GigabitEthernet0/0     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/1     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/2     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/3     unassigned      YES unset  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet1/0     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet1/1     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet1/2     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet1/3     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet2/0     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet2/1     unassigned      YES unset  up                    up      
Vlan123                123.123.123.2   YES manual up                    up
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
""
"r1"
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
GigabitEthernet0/0         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/1         123.123.123.1   YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/2         10.12.12.1      YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/3         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/4         unassigned      YES manual administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/5         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/6         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/7         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/8         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/9         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
Loopback0                  111.111.111.1   YES manual up                    up
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
""
"r2"
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
GigabitEthernet0/0         10.22.22.2      YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/1         10.21.21.2      YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/2         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/3         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/4         10.12.12.2      YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/5         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/6         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/7         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/8         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/9         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
Loopback0                  222.222.222.222 YES TFTP   up                    up
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
""
"r3"
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
GigabitEthernet0/0         123.123.123.3   YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/1         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/2         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/3         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/4         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/5         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/6         32.32.32.3      YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/7         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/8         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/9         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
""
"SW-2"
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
GigabitEthernet0/0     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/1     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/2     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/3     unassigned      YES unset  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet1/0     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet1/1     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet1/2     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet1/3     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet2/0     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet2/1     unassigned      YES unset  up                    up      
Vlan123                123.123.123.2   YES manual up                    up
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
""
"r1"
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
GigabitEthernet0/0         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/1         123.123.123.1   YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/2         10.12.12.1      YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/3         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/4         unassigned      YES manual administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/5         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/6         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/7         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/8         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/9         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
Loopback0                  111.111.111.1   YES manual up                    up
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
""
"r2"
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
GigabitEthernet0/0         10.22.22.2      YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/1         10.21.21.2      YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/2         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/3         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/4         10.12.12.2      YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/5         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/6         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/7         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/8         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/9         unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
Loopback0                  222.222.222.222 YES TFTP   up                    up
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
""
"r3"
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
GigabitEthernet0/0         123.123.123.3   YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/1         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/2         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/3         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/4         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/5         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/6         32.32.32.3      YES manual up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/7         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/8         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/9         unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down
```

Comment: Doublecheck the content of the directories `/etc/ansible/YAML_Files/Config-Change-Logs/` at the remote hosts, of course.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the original YAML file was that the final task, (named, "Merge All Files Into One") was being repetitively created because it was under the "hosts: all" section.

By creating another block within the playbook, having that block **only apply against "host: localhost"** and moving the task into that block, the play for creating the MergedFile.txt was only played once and create the desired, aggregate file without all the duplicated entries.

**Final (Working) Playbook**:

```
---
- 
  name: Aggregating Output From Network Devices
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

    - name: Sending a simple Cisco IOS command
      cisco.ios.ios_command:
        commands: 
          - show configuration history
      register: Bob


    - debug: var=Bob.stdout_lines


    - name: Send output to file
      copy: content="{{Bob.stdout[0]}}" dest=/etc/ansible/YAML_Files/Config-Change-Logs/{{inventory_hostname}}.txt

    - name: Prepend line to file
      blockinfile:
          path: /etc/ansible/YAML_Files/Config-Change-Logs/{{inventory_hostname}}.txt
          block: |
            ""
            "{{inventory_hostname}}"
          insertbefore: BOF

- 

  name: Merging All Output Into Single File
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

    - name: Merge All Files Into One
      assemble:
        src: /etc/ansible/YAML_Files/Config-Change-Logs/
        dest: /etc/ansible/YAML_Files/Config-Change-Logs/MergedFile.txt
```